# MongoDb Combine multiple results in a view

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

In MongoDb I want to create a view that combines data from 2 collections.

Structure:
**Event** : Id, Name, Date, Locations(LocationId, Date), **Location** Id, Name. **EventView** : Name, Date, Locations(LocationName, Date).

Example:

Events:

```
[{ Id: 1, Name: 'Event 1', Date:'2019-01-16', [{ LocationId: 1, Date:'2019-01-16'}, { LocationId: 2, Date: '2019-01-17'}]}, { Id:1, Name: 'Event 2', Date:'2019-01-18', [{ LocationId: 1, Date:'2019-01-18'}]}]
```

Locations:

```
[{ Id: 1,  Name: 'London' }, { Id: 2,  Name: 'New York' }]
```

Current code

```
db.createView("EventView", "Event",
[
 { $lookup: { from: "Location", localField: "Locations.Id", foreignField: "Id", as: "locations" } },
 { $project: { Id: 1, Name: 1, Date: 1, Locations: 1, "locations.Id": 1, "locations.Name": 1 } }
]
)
```

Current output:

```
[{ Name: 'Event 1', Date: '2019-01-16', Locations:[{ LocationId: 1, Date: '2019-01-16' }, { LocationId: 2, Date: '2019-01-17' }], locations: [{ Id: 1, Name: 'London' }, { Id: 2, Name: 'New York' }]}, { Name: 'Event 2', Date: '2019-01-18', Locations: [{ LocationId: 1, Date:'2019-01-18' }], locations: [{ Id: 1, Name: 'London' }]}]
```

Desired output:

```
[{ Name: 'Event 1', Date: '2019-01-16', Locations:[{ LocationName: 'London', Date: '2019-01-16' }, { LocationName: 'New York', Date: '2019-01-17' }]}, { Name: 'Event 2', Date: '2019-01-18', Locations: [{ LocationName: 'London' Date:'2019-01-18' }]}]
```

**Q**: What do I need to change in the code so that the **Locations** property is mapped as in the desired output example?

Comment: what is the output you're currently getting ?

Comment: @Visrozar Please check the updated question.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Locations property is mapped according to the definition", can you send the desired output ?